# How I can close the linked mentions in obsidian

Tags: settings, obsidian

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mwYg.png)
There shows up double linked mentions at the bottom of my page in two languages.
So frustrated, but I have already tried

1. fix the `more options` button on the right
2. change the hot keys
3. change the back linked in `settings`
4. reinstall obsidian
5. restart my computer
   But all I can do is closing the English version
   So sad, anyone could help, please

A new idea to fix it

Comment: You can try Aliases: https://forum.obsidian.md/t/include-aliases-in-the-unlinked-mentions/11422/4